# zipline ImportError: No module named 'pandas.io.data'

Tags: python, zipline

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 and I have uninstalled and installed Anaconda and packages(pandas, pandas-datareader) several times.
Now I installed zipline by pip install zipline but when I try to import zipline I got a importerror

```
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr  7 2018, 04:53:16) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zipline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\zipline\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import data
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import loader
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\zipline\data\loader.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas.io.data import DataReader
ImportError: No module named 'pandas.io.data'
```

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pandas`

Comment: I tried and prompt reply that requirement already satisfied. Problem remain unsolved

Comment: Try also  `python -m pip install pandas-datareader`